# How do you write a Spring Cloud Config Server with Spring Boot (1.5.3.RELEASE) and Spring Cloud Config (1.3.0.RELEASE)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I modified the spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb project to use the latest version of Spring Boot (1.5.3.RELEASE) and  Spring Cloud Config (1.3.0.RELEASE).
I also introduced the class MongoConfigServer that runs the mongo db config server.

When I run it, I get this error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository' available: 
more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [searchPathLocator, environmentRepository, searchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository]`

I am not sure what I did wrong.  How do I write my own config server without getting this error?
I don't see any documentation on how to do this.

Can somebody please help me, or guide me?

This mongo db config server used to work with older versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Config.
I am using this Mongo DB Config Server as an example for writing a different Config Server, which is also receiving the same error.

My fork of spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb is available at https://github.com/minmay/spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb.git

Answer (score 1):

The [spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb) project has been upgraded to use spring-boot 1.5.7 snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating https://github.com/minmay/spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/mongodb/config/MongoEnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.java.

What I did was I removed the searchPathLocator bean, and removed the primary annotation from environmentRepository.

I guess Spring Cloud Config was updated to conditionally find an environmentRepository bean.